# How to compute $\langle\delta(3t+1),\phi\rangle$ in the sense of Distribution?

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory, uniform-distribution, dirac-delta

Assuming $f(t)=3t+1 = s$, I got
$$\langle\delta(3t+1),\phi\rangle = \langle\delta(s),\phi(\frac{s-1}{3})\rangle = \frac{-1}{3}\langle\delta(s),\phi(\frac{s-1}{3})\rangle$$
but got stuck in here. How shall I proceed from here?

Comment: What is $\phi$?

Comment: Don't write $\langle\delta(s),\phi(\frac{s-1}{3})\rangle = \frac{-1}{3}\langle\delta(s),\phi(\frac{s-1}{3})\rangle.$ That is obviously not true unless both expressions vanish.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. By definition: $\langle \delta, \phi  \rangle = \int \delta(t) \phi(t) \ dt = \phi(0)$. Thus: $\int \delta(s) \phi(\frac{s-1}{3}) \ ds = \phi(\frac{s-1}{3})|_0=\phi(\frac{-1}{3})$. Integration here is an abuse of notation.